# Memberpress account form not showing custom fields

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Memberpress account form not showing custom fields, i have created a form usig Memberpress  fields and on fronend it is not showing the custom fields

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the show/hide feature on the custom field to make it show to the user.

If you want choose which fields show for specific memberships, you have to select "Customize User Information Fields" box under the Membership Options tab in ***Memberpress > Memberships > Your Membership Name***.

This is in the [MemberPress documentation](https://docs.memberpress.com/article/41-fields)